# pride ourselves on

Tags: word-usage

Is it appropriate to write "We **pride** ourselves **on** providing the best cable TV service in Tokyo. Therefore, we take your complaint seriously" in a response to a letter of complaint? I know the sentence is grammatical, but I have no idea whether it's appropriate. Would this sound like the author is boasting?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: It's in a pretty standard corporate register and there's nothing unidiomatic about **pride oneself on**. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prides+himself+on%2Cprides+herself+on%2Cpride+themselves+on%2Cpride+myself+on%2C+pride+ourselves+on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprides%20himself%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprides%20herself%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpride%20themselves%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpride%20myself%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpride%20ourselves%20on%3B%2Cc0  An alternative would be **take pride in**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having worked in a role that required me to address complaints before, it was our standard response to start our reply to ***every*** complaint with:

> Thank you for your email. We pride ourselves on our unrivalled user
>   experience, and as such, we are sorry to hear you're having issue with our
>   services....

It is standard in the customer services departments of large firms to have stock responses that are then tailored to the issue at hand. I wouldn't read too much into the individual boasting, especially if that individual has another mother tongue, it is likely they didn't write it.